# New Growl in App Store: Hide menubar icon?

Tags: osx-lion, growl, mac-app-store

I love growl – using it for years. I switched to a new Mac with OS X Lion and installed [growl from the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/growl/id467939042) (1,99 $ or so)

Now I have this growl menubar icon up left besides the date and battery. Since I use growl only for notifications and nothing else, I just don't need this icon up there. Just takes space.

I of course want growl still running in the background, just no menubar icon.

Any idea how to do so? There is no option in the growl settings!

Comment: A bit off-topic, but does this new version do anything new or why is it $1.99 now? Any new features? I guess the reason you can't remove the menubar is that it's also not installed as a preference pane anymore, right?

Comment: @slhck [Mac App Store - Growl](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/growl/id467939042) has some nice screenshots. It has a "Rollup window" for a history of recent notifications, and a history tab in the main window. The developer actually discontinued GrowlMail and GrowlTunes. For now the pre-MAS version still works, and you can still `brew install growlnotify`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious about the same thing so I took a look on their Twitter feed. Looks like it was a feature that didn't make it into the current release but it's slated for 1.3.1.

http://twitter.com/#!/GrowlMac/status/123829757191262208